# Is there a Radiators for Jenkins and Bamboo?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, bamboo

I need to bring our companies rather old build radiators upto standard so it reflects what our current toolstack looks like.
However, we're currently inside a weird limbo between using both Jenkins and Bamboo.

Is there an open source, off the shelf build radiator that can interact with both Bamboo and Jenkins? I've already had a crack at making my own system and decided that my JS skills are not up to the task.

Not essential but bonus points for pulling metrics from other sources like SonarQube and Jira...

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what information you are trying to "Radiate":

For an off-the-shelf solution that integrates with everything you mentioned you could check out Prometheus.  It has plugins for [Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217960/prometheus-exporter-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview), [Bamboo](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1218725/prometheus-exporter-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview), [Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/prometheus), and [SonarQube](https://github.com/dmeiners88/sonarqube-prometheus-exporter).

You could also opt for something quite a bit simpler and use the built in dashboards for the tools you are trying to display metrics for.  Just put them on different tabs and use an extension such as [Revolver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revolver-tabs/dlknooajieciikpedpldejhhijacnbda).

If you want to get a little more customized you can check out Elastic Stack's [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana).  The book [Agile Metrics in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/agile-metrics-in-action) has several examples of how to capture and display Atlassian data inside of Kibana.

Comment: I was toying with using revolver but I've been asked to ensure critical info is always displayed on all monitors. And there isn't enough screen real estate to split it sadly. I'll check out Prometheus and I hadn't thought of Kibana.